# Solr query with dynamic field

Tags: dynamic, solr, field

I have documents with the following `link.*` dynamic fields:

```
"docs": [{
    "id":"id1" 
    "link.1.text":"mytext"
    "link.1.nImg":1
    "link.2.text":"mytext"
    "link.2.nImg":2
}, {
    "id":"id2" 
    "link.1.text":"mytext"
    "link.1.nImg":1
    "link.2.text":"mytext"
    "link.2.nImg":1
}]
```

How can I get a query like : `link.*.text:"mytext"` or `link.*.nImg:2` ?

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't do that in Solr.

> Dynamic fields allow Solr to index fields that you did not explicitly
>   define in your schema. This is useful if you discover you have
>   forgotten to define one or more fields. Dynamic fields can make your
>   application less brittle by providing some flexibility in the
>   documents you can add to Solr.

In query you need to list exact name of a field name, so dynamic fields give you an index time flexibility

Some more info - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields

Comment: if you like this answer, you should vote it up and make it accepted answer