# find node with wildcard in the key field

Tags: java, solr, lucene, alfresco

For example I am trying to search something like:

```
@cm\:*ame:"pippo"
```

Is it possible?

We use alfresco 4.2 community edition, lucene locally and solr (1.4) in remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Wild card search is supported in Alfresco.
They query which you are using will look something like this.

**`@cm\:name:pippo*`**

You cannot use wild card on the property name because it should match exactly with model.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214704/1303832) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450681/1303832)

It is not possible in a simple query, and the solution with dynamicField/copyField is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes wild card is supported in both terms, phrases, and exact phrases.For more information please refer below link.Specially Wildcard Section.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Full_Text_Search_Query_Syntax#Wildcards

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't need full search text, only search in some "dynamic fields" by using wildcards in a field name in queries.